# How can I disable variable interpolation with the Perl substitution operator?

Tags: regex, perl, vms

I'm trying to replace a particular line in a text file on VMS.  Normally, this is a simple one-liner with Perl.  But I ran into a problem when the replacement side was a symbol containing a VMS path.  Here is the file and what I tried:

Contents of file1.txt:

```
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

Attempt to substitute 3rd line:

```
$ mysub = "disk$data1:[path.to]file.txt"
$ perl -pe "s/baz/''mysub'/" file1.txt
```

Yields the following output:

```
foo
bar
disk:[path.to]file.txt
quux
```

It looks like Perl was overeager and replaced the `$data1` part of the path with the contents of a non-existent variable (i.e., nothing).  Running with the debugger confirmed that.  I didn't supply `/e`, so I thought Perl should just replace the text as-is.  Is there a way to get Perl to do that?

(Also note that I can reproduce similar behavior at the linux command line.)

Comment: In Perl, you can disable variable-interpolation within `s///` by using the delimiter `'` instead of `/` (e.g. `s'baz'disk$data1:[path.to]file.txt'`). Unfortunately, judging from what you've posted, it looks like VMS uses `'` to perform its own variable substitution? So, it might be easier-said-than-done to get the single-quotes into the Perl script. :-/

Comment: Yep, I tried various flavors of that before posting here.  You need exactly two `''` and one `'` to do variable substitution on VMS, and its interpreter is easily confused.

Comment: When in doubt, use a script file instead of a one-liner. And use `use strict; use warnings;` If you had defined `my $mysub = 'disk$data1:[path.to]file.txt'` (note the single quotes to avoid variable interpolation) or even `my $mysub = $ENV{mysub]` (if you insist on using shell variables) inside a perl script, you would not have this problem.

Comment: @TLP: Actually, `$ENV{mysub}` would completely address the problem; that's the minimal fix. Instead of trying to disable the interpolation in Perl, the OP should disable the interpolation in VMS, by writing `perl -pe "s/baz/$ENV{mysub}/" file1.txt`!

Comment: `mysub` would have to be defined as a logical in that case, but yep, I think you're right.

Comment: @ruakh Perhaps that should be an answer then. I added one.

Comment: @TLP: Thanks, I've +1'd it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With just the right mix of quotes and double quotes you can get there:

We create a tight concatenation of "string" + 'substitute symbol' + "string".
The two double quoted strings contain single quotes for the substitute.
Contrived... but it works.

```
$ perl -pe "s'baz'"'mysub'"'" file1.txt
```

That's a DCL level solution.

For a Perl solution, use the `q()` operator for a non-interpolated string and execute that.
Stuff the symbol into the parens using simple DCL substitution.
This is my favorite because it (almost) makes sense to me and does not get too confusing with quotes.

```
$ perl -pe "s/baz/q(''mysub')/e" file1.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

As [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) discovered when reading my comment, the problem of perl interpolation can be solved by accessing the `%ENV` hash, rather than using a shell variable:

```
perl -pwe "s/baz/$ENV{mysub}/" file1.txt
```

Added `-w` because I do not believe in not using `warnings` even in one-liners.

Comment: Yes, this works (just tried it).  You need to use a logical instead of a symbol: `define mysub "disk$data1:[path.to]file.txt"`.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't even seen a VMS system in decades, but ... escape your sigil?

```
$ mysub = "disk\$data1:[path.to]file.txt"
```

or maybe

```
$ mysub = "disk\\$data1:[path.to]file.txt"
```

?

Comment: +1, that will work for this contrived case.  But what if I don't control `mysub`?

Comment: Not familiar with how the VMS shell works - TLP's answer is something I would try.

Answer (score 1):

For `sh` or a derivative, I'd use

```
perl -pe'BEGIN { $r = shift(@ARGV) } s/baz/$r/' "$mysub" file1.txt
```

Otherwise, you have to somehow covert the value of `mysub` into a Perl string literal. That would be more complicated. Find the equivalent for your shell.

**Edit by OP:**

Yes, this works.  The VMS equivalent is

```
perl -pe "BEGIN { $r = shift(@ARGV) } s/baz/$r/" 'mysub' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `$` with `\$`. Otherwise Perl sees a variable reference and replaces the string `$data1` with the content of `$data1` before the regular expression is evaluated. As you didn't define `$data1` it is, of course, empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
$ mysub='disk\$data1:[path.to]file.txt'
$ perl -pe 's/baz/'$mysub'/' FILE
foo
bar
disk$data1:[path.to]file.txt
quux
```

Comment: The single quotes are used for variable substitution on VMS, so that won't work.  It looks like it works on linux though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a logical name instead of a DCL symbol:

```
$ define mysub "disk$data1:[path.to]file.txt"
$ $ perl -pe "s/baz/mysub/" file1.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

**Use sed.**

Sed won't try to interpolate `$data1` as a variable, so you should get what you want.

```
$ sed -e "s/baz/''mysub'/" file1.txt
```